# How to have google docs api (nodejs) create an empty doc in a particular google account

Tags: node.js, express, google-api, google-drive-api, google-docs-api

I have an express.js application where clients authenticate using a local strategy (passport.js). After that I want them to be able to create empty documents with titles of their wish (I create a new mongoose 'Task' document and set its doclink (Task.doclink) to be the newly created document's public link (https://docs.google.com/document/d/...document_id.../edit)).

I want this new document to be created in a particular google account that I have access to (the clients don't have direct access to it but they can create documents inside it and write to it)

Any suggestions of how I should go about authorization of google API? As per my current research, this seems impossible.

Answer (score 0):

What I would recommend you to use is a [service account](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/service-accounts) as the docs say:

> A service account is an identity that an instance or an application
> can use to run API requests on your behalf.

What it means is that you will be able to have a "bot user" in your express app, which could be the interface between your users and your document.

### Docs

You can check more about it in these links:

- [Creating and managing service accounts](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-managing-service-accounts#iam-service-accounts-create-console).
- [Authenticating users with Node.js](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/getting-started/authenticate-users).